# How can I get my built-in microphone to work on a Lenovo G770?

Tags: 12.04, sound, microphone

I am dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo G770. The internal mic works fine in Windows 7. The mic is recognized and unmuted, but it just isn't detecting any sound. I tried messing around with pavucontrol settings, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with **hardware** configuration in Sound Settings.  You can get to sound settings by clicking on the volume icon in the upper tray.  I'm not at my Ubuntu machine right now, but I always put mine on Full Analog Duplex and it allows the mic to work.

Comment: Nah I don't think it's that. It's set to Analog Stereo Duplex right now. I had to go through PulseAudio Volume Control to configure that though, can that be done in the sound settings?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a G770, and I (finally) got my internal microphone working yesterday by following directions posted [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11979098).

Here's what I did:

1. Opened  "/etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf"  with sudo rights (in my case this file did not exist, so I simply created it)
2. Added the following line to "sound.conf":  "options snd-hda-intel model=asus"
3. Saved "sound.conf" and rebooted

BOOM, working microphone!

Comment: Any luck with this method, Abundant Victory?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type `alsamixer` there you will open a tool to manage all the sound devices, line ins, line outs etc.

[image]

Comment: addition to that. here you can find most of the commands to manage audio in linux. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture just take a look.

Comment: Hi, welcome to askubuntu. when adding images it is usually better to make them embedded as opposed to linked. I made the change for you, which will be visible once accepted.